# How to allow user to select a date and get every record with the same date in each of their timestamps? (Firebase Realtime Database)

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, datepicker, android-calendar

I'm trying to add a DatePicker for the user to choose a date from the calendar. Then, I'm using Firebase query `equalTo(dateSelected.getTime())` to check whether the timestamps in every record match the selected date. If they match, they will be printed out in the recycler view.

Initially, when user enters this page, the app will display all the records on the recycler view. After user selects the date, by right the records must be shown according to what the user selects, but now it shows nothing. The pictures show how the page looks like and the data from Firebase. Thanks for reading this and helping out.

The error: As I select a date from the calendar, it went blank. There are no data printed out on the recycler view. In Logccat, there is an error `W/System: A resource failed to call close.` What does this mean?

[image: How the page looks like] [image: Table from Firebase]

```
public class DailyBreach extends AppCompatActivity implements DailyBreachRVAdapter.BreachClickInterface{
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private ArrayList<ppeBreachModel> ppeBreachModelArrayList;
    private DailyBreachRVAdapter dailyBreachRVAdapter;
    EditText dateInput;
    Button dateBtn, submitDate;
    Context context;
    Locale id = new Locale("en", "MY");
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy", id);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date dateSelected;
    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    AlertDialog builderAlert;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    View showInput;
    Query query;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily_breach);

        dateInput = findViewById(R.id.dateInput);
        dateBtn = findViewById(R.id.dateBtn);
        submitDate = findViewById(R.id.submitDate);
        context = this;
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        firebaseDatabase = firebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("PPEBreach");
        query = databaseReference.orderByChild("timestamp");
        ppeBreachModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        dailyBreachRVAdapter = new DailyBreachRVAdapter(ppeBreachModelArrayList, this, this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(dailyBreachRVAdapter);

        getAllBreach();

        dateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                        calendar.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
                        dateInput.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
                        dateSelected = calendar.getTime();

                        String input = dateInput.getText().toString();
                        if(input.isEmpty()) {
                            submitDate.setEnabled(false);
                        } else {
                            submitDate.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    }
                }, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        submitDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Query query = database.child("PPEBreach").orderByChild("timestamp").equalTo(dateSelected.getTime());
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        showLisener(snapshot);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void showLisener(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        ppeBreachModelArrayList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot item : snapshot.getChildren()) {
            ppeBreachModel ppeBreachModel = item.getValue(ppeBreachModel.class);
            ppeBreachModelArrayList.add(ppeBreachModel);
        }
        dailyBreachRVAdapter = new DailyBreachRVAdapter(ppeBreachModelArrayList, this, this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(dailyBreachRVAdapter);
    }

    private void getAllBreach(){
        ppeBreachModelArrayList.clear();
        query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                ppeBreachModelArrayList.add(snapshot.getValue(ppeBreachModel.class));
                dailyBreachRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                dailyBreachRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                dailyBreachRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                dailyBreachRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBreachClick(int position) {

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for mentioning, I've shared the problem I'm getting at the post.